# Jquery blur + enter on jquery dialog

Tags: jquery

my blur event doesn't work using this code the enter event works just fine.

```
$(document).on('blur keyup', "#classsection",function(event) {  
    // do your stuff here  
    var section = $(this).val(); 
    var controll = $(this).attr("controll");

    if(section != ""){
        switch(controll){
            case 'enrollment':
                if(event.keyCode == '13')  {
                    var idno = $("#idno").val();
                    sectionInfo(section);
                    enrollmentSubjects(idno,section);
                }
            break;
            case 'classes':
                if(event.type == 'blur' || event.keyCode == '13')  {
                    sectionSubjects(section);
                }
            break;
            case 'copyclass':
                if(event.type == 'blur' || event.keyCode == '13')  {
                    alert(controll);
                }
            break;
        }//end of switch
    }else{
        $("#yearlevel").val("");    
    }});
```

if i use this one below it will work on the page but not in the modal dialog

```
$("#classsection").on('blur keyup',function(event)
```

but the one above the enter will work but not the blur

Comment: Did you tried using `focusout` ?

Comment: What is the error in the console?

Comment: it has no error in the console. the blur is not the working when im using $(document) instead of $("#classsection")

Comment: ive figured it out thanks @MilanChheda the focusout did the trick